# What is the use of Use Proxy Integration in API Gateway Integration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, aws-api-gateway, endpoint

I am trying to make a integration between API Gateway API and a resource behind VPC.

While creating the integration, there is a option to select, "Use Proxy Integration". Even if I am not selecting this check box and deploy the API, I am able to make the API Gateway connectivity working via NLB to the target resource behing VPC.

[image]

So, I am having difficulty in understanding still why we need to select the check box.

Comment: Have your read this? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy

This might also be interesting: https://www.stackery.io/blog/why-you-should-use-api-gateway-proxy-integration-with-lambda/